# How do I use union on views, when one of them have additional column

Tags: oracle, postgresql, union-all

I have two views that load basically exact same columns with exeption of one column. When I try to use union all on them I cannot because The columns do not match on table a. If i add that column to union table i get the same message on table b. How do i use union and make it work, when one of the views have aditional column

Comment: Please check [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: You can use `FULL OUTER JOIN`

Comment: sample data and expected output will help us to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just add a NULL column to make up for the column not being present.

For example:

```
SELECT a, b, c, NULL AS d
FROM tablea
UNION ALL
SELECT a, b, c, d
FROM tableb;
```

Comment: Would that not bring problems for the gui team, that uses data given from that view?

Comment: What is the output you are expecting that would work for the GUI team?